# ternary operator in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ternary-operator

I am trying to do conditional check using ternary operator in nodejs.

The ternary operator is working fine without issues in below scenario. It prints text in console

```
{true ? (
  console.log("I am true")      
) : (
  console.log("I am not true")
)}
```

And the same is not working under below scenario and it throws following error

> let text = "I am true";
>
> ```
>   ^^^^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

```js
{true ? (
  let text = "I am true";
  console.log(text);      
) : (
  console.log("I am not true")
)}
```

I am unable to understand why this is behaving differently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What follows the `?` or the `:` in the conditional (ternary) operator must be an *expression*, not statements. Expressions evaluate to a value. Variable assignment, like `let text = "I am true";`, is a *statement*, not an expression - it *does* something (assigns "I am true" to the `text` variable) rather than *evaluating* to some value.

You also can't have semicolons inside of parentheses, when those parentheses are expected to evaluate to an expression. If you *really* wanted to, you could use the comma operator instead, though it's a bit confusing:

```js
let text;
(true ? (
  text = "I am true",
  console.log(text)
) : (
  console.log("I am not true")
))
```

But the conditional operator still isn't appropriate for this situation - the conditional operator *evaluates* to a value (it's an expression in itself). If you aren't going to use the resulting value, you should use `if/else` instead:

```js
let text;
if (true) {
  text = "I am true";
  console.log(text);
} else console.log("I am not true");
```

The time to use the conditional operator is when you need to use the resulting value, for example:

```js
const condition = true;
const text = condition ? 'I am true' : 'I am not true';
console.log(text);
```

(See how the result of the conditional operation is being *used* here - it's being assigned to the `text` variable.)

Answer (score 3):

You can't do assignment like that in a ternary operator. You would need to do something like:

```
let text = myCondition
              ? "I am true"
              : "I am not true"
```

Comment: Ok but what if I wanted to do some business logic over there?

Comment: @Think-Twice You don't, conditional _operator_  is not purposed to replace `if..else` _statement_. Use statements where appropriate, and operators where they are demanded.

Answer (score 0):

```
let text;

true ? (text = "I am true") : (text = "I am not true");

console.log(text);
```